# NodeJS MongoDB crashing "Parameter must be object"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, object, mongoose

When I run my server and send the form nickname to the database, my program crashes! It's telling me it's because it needs to be an object. it runs fine if I change the req.body.pickname to just req.body but then the data I need to save doesn't get saved. Is there a way to turn this into an object, or to make this work?

server.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));



var PORT = 45050;

app.use("/", express.static(__dirname));
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/thisworks", {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});


var gameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nickname: String
});
var User = mongoose.model("wowww", gameSchema);


app.post("/addname", (req, res) =>{
    var playerNickname = new User(req.body.pickname);
    playerNickname.save()
    .then(item => {
        console.log("nickname created " + req.body.pickname);

    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
        console.log("error baby!");
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log("server is up and running using port " + PORT)
});
```

index.html

```
<form method="post" action="/addname">
    <h1 class="center-align"> <input id="pickName" class="center-align" type='text' name='pickname' placeholder='Nickname' required> </h1>
    <h1 class='center-align'><input id='rea2dy' value=" Ready >" type='submit'></h1>               
 </form>
```

This is the error I get if that helps.

```
ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object, got 
redditaza
at new ObjectParameterError (C:\Users\10FGD\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\objectParameter.js:25:11)
at model.Document (C:\Users\10FGD\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:89:11)
at model.Model (C:\Users\10FGD\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:104:12)
at new model (C:\Users\10FGD\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4656:15)
at app.post (C:\Users\10FGD\Desktop\Games\doubleTheTrouble\server.js:27:26)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\10FGD\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\10FGD\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\10FGD\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\10FGD\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\Users\10FGD\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\10FGD\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\Users\10FGD\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at serveStatic (C:\Users\10FGD\node_modules\express\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:75:16)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\10FGD\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (C:\Users\10FGD\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
at C:\Users\10FGD\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
```

I should note that the code that's in my console.log() works just fine, and that's what I would like to have sent to my database.

Comment: In your `console.log`, you should print `item`, not `req.body.pickname`.

Comment: thanks good point, I was just wondering what req.body.pickname was sending to the db that made it keep crashing, but it didn't show me much unfortunately.

Comment: hmm just put item and instead of returning my string it returned: { _id: 5e8576fc036a403d1c1bcfc9, __v: 0 } I'm not familiar with  mongodb this is all so foreign to me! lol

Answer (score 0):

this seemed to work incase anyone in the future has the same problem. i used mongodb instead of mongoose require

But if you have a solution that works with mongoose please post it :)

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();


var PORT = 3332;

app.use("/", express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/thisworks", {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});
   var db = mongoose.connection;
   db.once('open', function(cb) {
   console.log("connection established");
})


app.post("/addname", (req, res) =>{
    var name = req.body;
    var data = {
        "nickname": name
    }
    db.collection('wowww').insertOne(data, function(err, coll) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('rec estab');
    });

});






app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log("server is up and running using port " + PORT)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var cors = require('cors')
const app = express();

// CORS Middleware
app.use(cors());
// Logger Middleware
app.use(morgan('dev'));
// Bodyparser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());


const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "uri";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
client.connect(err => {
  console.log('MongoDB Connected...')
  const collection = client.db("dbname").collection("collectionname");

  app.post('/name', (req, res) => {
    collection. insertOne({ name: req.body.name })
    res.send("data added")
  });

});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.